# How to start an activity by passing a non-parcelable object to it?

Tags: android

I use a third-party API ([JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/)) and I would like to start an activity with an object of this API (`AudioFile`).

The problem is this object does not implement Parcelable or Serializable.

What is the best way to do this ?

---

EDIT

Google's answer : http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html

Comment: You can use `public static` objects

Comment: @BatuhanC `public static` objects will expose my objects to the whole program. It is unsafe, isn't it ?
Is it the only way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, none of which are easy or perfect (depending on the object and use-case).

1. Create a custom object that extends the `AudioFile` object and implements either `Serializable` or `Parcelable` - which can be tedious, but not impossible. With custom objects like this, the documentation may be lacking for this option.
2. Someone mentioned `static` as an option. This can generally work well, except you are talking about Android. Android can destroy and re-create the JVM for your app at any time when it is not visible to the user. So, if this `AudioFile` class is playing in the background in your app, strange behavior could occur if Android decides to kill the process.
3. You can use an object in the `Application` class, but is potentially has the same issues as #2.
4. Use `SharedPreferences` and some kind of index system to retrieve the file.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for this comprehensive response.
In my case, I can recreate my `AudioFile` from a `File`.
`File` implements `Serializable`, so I can pass it with an intent.
I think it is another possibility if the creation does not take time.

Comment: Use EventBus. So much easier and has a lot of other nice usages

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class of your own, which would accept an object of type AudioFile, and populate fields with its values.

```
public class MyAudioFile implements Parcelable{

private File file;
//other fields...

public MyAudioFile(AudioFile audioFile){
   this.file = audioFile.getFile();
   //populate other fields
}

//parcelable stuff

}
```

Comment: What about object with high complexity ? In my case `AudioFile` contains a lot of stuff (Actually, all of the ID3 metadatas found in the audio file and much more) and it is unthinkable to retrieve all the fields. However I do not know how internally it works and I maybe will make mistake.